# How can I import .dmp file (export from 10g express edition) into oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

I export database from oracle 10g express edition with the command:

`expdp old_database/123456 schemas =old_database directory=datadump_dir  dumpfile=databasebackup.dmp logfile=databasebackup.log`

and import into Oracle Database Express Edition 11g Release 2s with the command `impdp new_database/123456 directory=datadump_dir dumpfile=databasebackup.dmp logfile=new.log remap_schema=old_database:new_database`

and the command `imp new_database/123456@localhost file=databasebackup.dmp log=new.log full=y`

Both of them show error:

**IMP-00010: not a valid export file, header failed verification**

**IMP-00000: Import terminated unsuccessfully**

I am using windown 64bit. 
How can I solve the problem ?

I also have a question, How I can read (open) .dmp file ?

Thank you for support!

Comment: Have you tried some searching? Have you tried something? if so, please post what you tried and the problems you are having

Comment: sorry I edit the question.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full export and import commands you actually used; and the version you were using for each (e.g. 10g exp, 11g imp). Is there are reason you aren't using datapump export/import? (From the error I'm wondering if you did a datapump export with `expdp`, and are now trying to import it with legacy `imp`)

Comment: Yes I export database with `expdp` and import with `imp`. I also edit my question, please help me.

Comment: If it was exported with `expdp` then you have to use `impdp`. IMP-00010 probably indicates the file has been corrupted somehow. Perhaps try exporting again?

Comment: I only have file .dmp export from oracle 10g not install oracle 10 now.

Comment: You get exactly the same error with `impdp` and `imp`? I'd expect `imp` to error, you have to use `impdp`. How did you get the dump file - did you export it or was it sent to you? Or did you do copy the file from one machine to another? If so how? Maybe it was corrupted by FTP; or was sent compressed and you've uncompressed it incorrectly (or just renamed a compressed file).

Comment: I get the .dmp file from another computer ? maybe the file was wrong, I will request other file again. How can I open the file to view table ? thank for support me.

Comment: @NguyenDuong - you can't really view the file contents, it's a proprietary format. How did you get the file from one computer to the other? For instance, ftp in ascii mode will corrupt it because it's a binary file.